# Communicate between docker containers without using docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a flask app that runs using docker-compose and has 2 services listed in my docker-compose file - 1 for my flask app and 1 for nginx. I'd like to deploy to AWS Lightsail, but that unfortunately does not allow me to use docker-compose. Instead I have to build each as a separate images and deploy them to my Lightsail instance.

I'm able to build and run my flask app service on my computer, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle the networking between the flask container and the nginx container since docker-compose handled networking automatically.

I was able to get them to communicate by inspecting the flask container with `docker container inspect <CONTAINER_ID>` to get the ip address. I then hardcoded the value in my nginx `default.conf` file and re-built, but obviously that's not practical.

Here's a shortened version of my docker-compose file showing how I was connecting them previously.

```
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    ....
    environment:
      - FLASK_SERVER_ADDR=flask-app:8001 
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - flask-app
    ....
  flask-app:
   ....
    command: sh -c "gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8001 'main.start()'"
```

Inside my nginx `default.conf` file I reference the `FLASK_SERVER_ADDR` environment variable like this

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://$FLASK_SERVER_ADDR;
    ...
  }
```

I used `docker network ls` to view which networks available and tried using the bridge network like this `docker build -t nginx-proxy --build-arg FLASK_SERVER_ADDR=${bridge:8001} nginx` but the value doesn't even seem to be set. When I try to run the nginx container after building I get this error with what seems to be an empty hostname `no host in upstream "" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:7`.

How can I get these two containers to build and communicate on the same network without docker-compose? Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting docker containers to talk to each other using Lightsail virtual servers service or Lightsail containers service (https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/features/)? If you are using Lightsail container service, check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6S2brobgmBA video.